# Example of connected Hausdorff space $X$ and surjective continous map $f:X\to X\times X$

Tags: gn.general-topology

What is an example of a connected Hausdorff space $X$ with $|X|>1$ and a surjective continous map $f:X\to (X\times X)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$X=[0,1]$. See [Space-filling curve.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve)

Comment: You can also do this with any positive dimensional connected manifold I think.

Answer (score 5):

The Hilbert cube $[0,1]^\omega$. Just split the coordinates in two disjoint infinite sets. Most standard sequence spaces like $\ell^\infty, \ell^2$ will similarly work.

Comment: Those examples even have $X$ and $X\times X$ homeomorphic.